# Coordinates changing keys using Google Places

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places API for my [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) app. The data model of coordinates it gave before was

```
{A: 12.879721, F: 121.77401699999996}
```

Now it's like this:

```
{G: 12.879721, K: 121.77401699999996}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What programming language? [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use undocumented properties (they change, or can, with every release of the API). Use the documented methods (.lat() and .lng()).