# Google Maps Mystery Unit -- ca?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on understanding user events in Google Maps. Here's my sample code:

```
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(e){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
});
```

The console returns:

```
{
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 36.29330392714158,
        "lng": -115.24877548232325
    },
    "pixel": {
        "x": 581.5555419921875,
        "y": 374.7916578363487
    },
    "ca": {
        "x": 46.04531521257013,
        "y": 100.26925500235961
    }
}
```

So I understand Latitude and Longitude.

The Pixel coordinates seems to represent the display on my webpage (with html canvas like output) When I move the cursor to the upper left corner of the visible map element in my web page, and right click, the console shows nearly 0,0 .  Lower right hand corner matches to the pixel height / width of my display.  So I can deduce that the Pixel feedback represents the display on my webpage.

I don't understand the context for a 'ca'? In fact what is a 'ca'?  Anybody know?   Is that an abbreviation for something?  I can see that the 'ca' value barely changes when I right click on different areas of the visible map. I have no clue where 'ca' 0,0 ends up. How would you use a 'ca' element, what is it for?   Anybody have an official reference?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ca` is an undocumented property of the object created by the closure compiler.

It will (or at least can) change with every release of the API so should not be used.

Related questions:

- [Google.Maps.Event settings - Va versus Xa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816294/google-maps-event-settings-va-versus-xa)
- [Google Places coordinates changing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711938/google-places-coordinates-changing-keys)
- [Google Map Api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442876/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-null)
- [Google Maps API V3 - only showing a blank map when using the geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114797/google-maps-api-v3-only-showing-a-blank-map-when-using-the-geocoder)
  -[Google maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614504/google-maps-weird-geometry-location-attributes-g-k)
- [Google maps api: what are xa and pa in get bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393961/google-maps-api-what-are-xa-and-pa-in-get-bounds)
- [item.geometry.location.kb & item.geometry.location.jb returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined)